# Proving the Commutativity of Set intersection.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Hi this is basically the question:

Write down a formula which states that for any two sets $X$ and $Y$ ,
the set $X \cap Y$ is the same as the set $Y \cap X$. Then, prove this statement. The
union $X \cup Y$ of two sets is defined as the set $X \cup Y = \{x\mid x \in  X] \vee [x ∈ Y ]\}$

This is what I did

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be arbitrary sets

Proof.

Let $x \in (X \cap Y )$

$x \in X \wedge x \in Y$ (By definition of Set Intersection)

$\implies x \in Y \wedge x \in X$ (Conjunction is Commutative)

$\implies x \in \{x\mid [x \in Y ] \wedge [x \in X]\}$

$\implies x \in (Y \cap X)$

That is what I did for the first part of the question

**Second Part**

Now proving Union.

Proof. $X \cup Y$ means that the set that consists of all the elements which are
contained in either (or both) $X$ and $Y$.

Let: $x \in (X \cup Y)$ (By definition of set Union)

$\implies x \in X \vee x \in Y$ (Expansion of set Union)

$\implies x \in \{x\mid [x \in X] \vee [x \in Y ]\}$

$\implies x \in  \{x\mid[x \in Y ] \vee [x \in X]\}$ (Disjunction is Commutative)

$\implies x \in (Y \cup Z)$

Did I understand the first part of the question correctly? Kind of confused with that they mean by a formula.

Is my use of the implication sign correct?

Also we can use all the axioms and theorems related to Set Theory.

Comment: $x \in x | \ldots$ makes no sense. In addition, the $\Rightarrow$s prove only the inclusion : $(X \cap Y) \subseteq (Y \cap X)$

Comment: Doesn't the x ∈ x | mean that "x such that x" ?  And must it be a both ways implication sign?

Comment: Yes for bi-implication. Upon formuale editing, now I understand: but the third line is not necessary; after 2nd line (Conjunction is Commutative) you can directly "jump" to 4th line (By definition of Set Intersection) again